# Is it possible to know if a ui.router state is already declared in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is my $stateProvider config

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
var helloState = {
    name: 'uploadForm',
    url: '/uploadForm',
    templateUrl: 'templates/step_Form/form.html?v=' + new Date().getDay()
}

var uploadState = {
    name: 'uploadForm.upload',
    url: '/upload',
    templateUrl: 'templates/step_Form/form-upload.html?v=' + new Date().getDay()
}


var contentState = {
    name: 'uploadForm.content',
    url: '/content',
    templateUrl: 'templates/step_Form/form-content.html?v=' + new Date().getDay()
}

$stateProvider.state(helloState);
$stateProvider.state(uploadState);
$stateProvider.state(contentState);

})
```

Is it possible to testif state is already declared?

Like this :

```
if($stateProvider.state.??? == null)
   $stateProvider.state(helloState);
```

Because i have another page with a redirection, and it passes twice in the config and make an error 'State helloState is already declared'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$state.get()`, which returns an array of all declared states within your `$stateProvider`.

Of course, you'd have to inject `$state` where you want to perform the check.